# Интервал с определенным шагом в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ли возможность указать шаг в интервале при вставке множества значений в таблицу с помощью `UPDATE` в MS SQL? Например, хотелось бы обновить значения в таблице, где `ID` будет в интервале от 100 до 500 с шагом 30. Либо в качестве альтернативы как можно обойтись без интервала, чтоб обновление происходило в цикле в определенном промежутке с конкретным шагом? Ниже укажу пример кода, в котором хотелось бы реализовать это, если возможно.

```
UPDATE Rates
  SET
      Amount =
(
    SELECT Amount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT KK.Amount,
               KK.OperationName
        FROM
        (
            SELECT R.Col1,
                   R.RateID,
                   JJ.Type,
                   FLOOR(JJ.AmountMin + RAND() * (JJ.AmountMax + 1 - JJ.AmountMin)) AS Amount,
                   JJ.OperationName,
                   JJ.Currency
            FROM Rates R
                 LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM OriginTransacts OT
                WHERE OT.Period = 'Month'
                      AND OT.OperationName = 'Clothes Shopping'
            ) AS JJ ON R.RateID = FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 10)
        ) AS KK
    ) AS LL
    WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL
),
      OperationName =
(
    SELECT OperationName
    FROM
    (
        SELECT KK.Amount,
               KK.OperationName
        FROM
        (
            SELECT R.Col1,
                   R.RateID,
                   JJ.Type,
                   FLOOR(JJ.AmountMin + RAND() * (JJ.AmountMax + 1 - JJ.AmountMin)) AS Amount,
                   JJ.OperationName,
                   JJ.Currency
            FROM Rates R
                 LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM OriginTransacts OT
                WHERE OT.Period = 'Month'
                      AND OT.OperationName = 'Clothes Shopping'
            ) AS JJ ON R.RateID = FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 10)
        ) AS KK
    ) AS LL
    WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE Rates.RateID IN(FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1110), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1140), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1170), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1200), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1230), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1260), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1290), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1320), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1350), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1380), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1410), FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 1440))
      AND Rates.Amount IS NULL;
```

Comment: курсор не рассматриваете?

Comment: Честно говоря, пока совсем новичок в этом деле. Рассмотрю, если вы подскажете как его можно в моем примере использовать.

Comment: или `WHILE` с инкрементом +30

Comment: C `WHILE` пробовал, но не получалось. Либо я неправильно скрипт писал, либо это не работает.

Comment: У вас для обновления двух полей используются вложенные запросы, которые идентичны - отличие только в возвращаемом поле, что по моему мнению не очень оптимально. Можно вынести подзапрос в JOIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пока так, навскидку:

```
DECLARE @i INT= 100;

WHILE @i <= 500
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Rates
          SET
              Amount =
        (
            SELECT Amount
            FROM
            (
                SELECT KK.Amount,
                       KK.OperationName
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT R.Col1,
                           R.RateID,
                           JJ.Type,
                           FLOOR(JJ.AmountMin + RAND() * (JJ.AmountMax + 1 - JJ.AmountMin)) AS Amount,
                           JJ.OperationName,
                           JJ.Currency
                    FROM Rates R
                         LEFT JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM OriginTransacts OT
                        WHERE OT.Period = 'Month'
                              AND OT.OperationName = 'Clothes Shopping'
                    ) AS JJ ON R.RateID = FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 10)
                ) AS KK
            ) AS LL
            WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL
        ),
              OperationName =
        (
            SELECT OperationName
            FROM
            (
                SELECT KK.Amount,
                       KK.OperationName
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT R.Col1,
                           R.RateID,
                           JJ.Type,
                           FLOOR(JJ.AmountMin + RAND() * (JJ.AmountMax + 1 - JJ.AmountMin)) AS Amount,
                           JJ.OperationName,
                           JJ.Currency
                    FROM Rates R
                         LEFT JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM OriginTransacts OT
                        WHERE OT.Period = 'Month'
                              AND OT.OperationName = 'Clothes Shopping'
                    ) AS JJ ON R.RateID = FLOOR(RAND() * 5 + 10)
                ) AS KK
            ) AS LL
            WHERE Amount IS NOT NULL
        )
        WHERE Rates.RateID = @i
              AND Rates.Amount IS NULL;
        SET @i+=30;
    END;
```

Comment: А начальное значение интервала можно указать сразу после `BEGIN` как `SET @i=300`, например?

Comment: начальное значение указано в самом начале, при объявлении переменной `@i`

Comment: Да, так все работает. Благодарю. У меня почему-то выскакивала ошибка о необходимости объявить переменную, хотя вроде делал также.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Вообще цикл совершенно не нужен, достаточно просто условия `where Rates.RateID between 100 and 500 AND Rates.RateID % 30 = 0`

Comment: совершенно верно

Comment: Вот, возможно, это мне и нужно было. Я почему-то сомневался, что сработает выражение с остатком. Я использовал похожее, но в другом скрипте - там не сработало.  Но у этого метода не будет возможности добавлять различные значения, как при помощи `WHILE`, все значения будут одинаковыми. Я прав?

Comment: в любом случае можете использовать переменные, вместо жёстких значений

Comment: @Anatol уже все понял. Спасибо.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Разные значения - не проблема, делаете подзапрос вида `(select 1 a, 20 b union select 2, 48 union select 3, 89 ...) X` и подклеиваете его к запросу, например по равенству поля `a`, а из `b` берете новое значение. или просто с помощью `case when`. В одном запросе, без циклов можно сделать практически все что угодно

Comment: @Mike Буду иметь в виду и такой вариант. Пока для меня это немного сложновато понять, но буду стараться. Спасибо.

Comment: При использовании where Rates.RateID between 100 and 500 AND Rates.RateID % 30 = 0, как подсказывает Mike, не попадут в выборку начальное и конечное значения идентфикатора, т.е. 100 и 500. Но возможно автору и не требуется, чтобы они попадали

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin да и 0 остаток не всегда будет равен, но это не суть, суть же понятна

Comment: @Anatol, согласен. Решение действительно простое

Answer (score 1):

Думаю необходимо сначала сгенерировать ряд идентфикаторов с нужным шагом и далее уже его применить при обновлении. 
Пример:

```
DECLARE @BeginID INT = 100 -- начальное значение идентификатора
  , @EndID INT = 500 -- конечное значение идентификатора
  , @Step INT = 30; -- шаг

WITH CTE (id)
AS (
  SELECT @BeginID

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id + @Step
  FROM CTE
  WHERE id + @Step <= @EndID
  )

UPDATE Rates SET
  -- ваш код обновления полей
FROM CTE
WHERE Rates.RateID = CTE.ID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```